# Choosing the second element with XML Parsing with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I tried to parse my XML file. It works, but i would like to parse only the second Song Element only. How I could do that ?

I tried to modify and change .each, but didn't worked...

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Event status="happened">
  <Song title="GOODBYE (FEAT. LYSE)">
   <Artist name="FEDER">
   </Artist>
    <Info StartTime="23:10:54" ID="333" />
  </Song>
  <Song title="HOW YOU REMIND ME">
   <Artist name="NICKELBACK">
   </Artist>
    <Info StartTime="23:15:49" ID="295" />
  </Song>
 </Event>
```

The jQuery script

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var myObj = {}; 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Play.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('Song').each(function(){

                    myObj.title = $(this).attr('title');
                    $(this).find('Artist').each(function(){


                        myObj.artist = $(this).attr('name');
                    });
                    $(this).find('Info').each(function(){

                        myObj.time = $(this).attr('StartTime');
                        myObj.id = $(this).attr('ID');
                    });

                    $('.history').append( "<div><img src='/covers/"+myObj.id+".jpg'></div><div class='style=float:left'><div class='time'>"+myObj.time+" {"+myObj.id+"}</div><div class='artist'>"+myObj.artist+"</div><div class='title'>"+myObj.title+"</div></div>" );
                });
            }
        }); 

    });
    </script>

    <div class="history"></div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the song element by it's index using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). Then for each of the children you don't need an `each` since there is only one of each tag

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Play.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

      var $song = $(xml).find('Song').eq(1),
        $info = $song.find('Info'),
        $artist = $song.find('Artist');

      var myObj = {
        title: $song.attr('title'),
        artist: $artist.attr('name'),
        time: $info.attr('StartTime'),
        id: $info.attr('ID')
      };

      $('.history').append("<div><img src='/covers/" + myObj.id + ".jpg'></div><div class='style=float:left'><div class='time'>" + myObj.time + " {" + myObj.id + "}</div><div class='artist'>" + myObj.artist + "</div><div class='title'>" + myObj.title + "</div></div>");

    }
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/eTEFwOy37mBD1WodfbzX?p=preview)**</kbd>